# Selecting All FORM Elements Except in Certain Area(s)

Tags: jquery

Maybe my understanding of the NOT Selector is wrong....but I am trying to select every element on a form that is NOT in a certain 'area' of the FORM.

I am trying to grab every element except for those within the "meter-detail" area of the overall form.

- THIS FAILS: `$('form').not('.meter-detail')`
- THIS FAILS: `$('form:not(.meter-detail)')`

HTML SAMPLE:
Only the top 4 & bottom 4 elements should be chosen. Nothing in the "meter-detail" area should be chosen.

```
<form>
     <input id="Entity_DeviceName" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="Entity_BalancedZone" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="Entity_FlowDirection" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="Entity_AreaName" type="text" value="Intrastate" />

     <div class="meter-detail">
          <div class="meter-blade" data-id="1">
               <input id="Entity_MeterName" type="text" value="1111" />
               <input id="Entity_MeterNumber" type="text" value="1111" />
          </div>
          <div class="meter-blade" data-id="2">
               <input id="Entity_MeterName" type="text" value="2222" />
               <input id="Entity_MeterNumber" type="text" value="2222" />
          </div>
     </div>

     <input id="Entity_Producer" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="Entity_ProducerContactName" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="Entity_ProducerPhone" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="Entity_ProducerEmail" type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

However, upon inspection...

[image]

Comment: `$("form > input")` ?

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how CSS selectors work. This does not fail, it simply selects all form tags which don't have the `meter-detail` class itself. If you want to select an item based on it's child elements, you have to take a different approach via JS

Comment: @cloned Yeah...I can see that now.  Thanks.

Comment: Solution reframe: put the ones you *do* want inside another div then select that div `$("form > div.form-inputs")`   - though depends on what you're using `form` or the result of the selector for.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah...I decided to do just that.  I was hoping for something more "eloquent".  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no selector to explicitly exclude elements based on a parent. However you can achieve what you need by using `filter()` and providing your own logic to check for that parent element. Try this:

```js
let $inputs = $('form :input').filter((i, el) => $(el).closest('.meter-detail').length == 0);

$inputs.addClass('foo'); // just for this demo
```

```css
input { 
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 2px;
}

.foo {
  background-color: #5dda5d2e;
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="Entity_DeviceName" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="Entity_BalancedZone" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="Entity_FlowDirection" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="Entity_AreaName" type="text" value="Intrastate" />

  <div class="meter-detail">
    <div class="meter-blade" data-id="1">
      <input id="Entity_MeterName" type="text" value="1111" />
      <input id="Entity_MeterNumber" type="text" value="1111" />
    </div>
    <div class="meter-blade" data-id="2">
      <input id="Entity_MeterName" type="text" value="2222" />
      <input id="Entity_MeterNumber" type="text" value="2222" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <input id="Entity_Producer" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="Entity_ProducerContactName" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="Entity_ProducerPhone" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="Entity_ProducerEmail" type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

Note that this is assuming that your HTML in the working version is more complex than displayed in the question, otherwise you can simply use:

```
let $inputs = $('form > :input');
```

Comment: I can see why this would work...and will probably have to mark it as the answer.  However, the "simple" example (above) is not comprehensive.  The actual form contains a TON of other element types.  Is there a way to choose all elements in the undesired areas...and then...filter against those?

Comment: That would potentially work too, however it would not be an ideal solution as you'd need multiple loops, instead of one as in this example. Note that I used `:input` in the above example, not `input`, so that it captures all types of form controls, `input`, `select`, `textarea` etc - if that's the issue you're referring to.

Comment: Yeah...I can see that now.  It looks like my only real choice is to segregate the page into various "named divs" and select across that.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

`let elements = $('form *').not('.meter-detail, .meter-detail *');`